# Read large zip files in an angular electron app

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, webassembly

In my usecase i need to read large zip files in an angular electron app.
So far I use jszip but there is a limit of the zip file size of 1GB (32bit version) and 2 GB (64 bit).
I can not unzip the file when the zip files are larger.
Are there other possibilities? Would webassembly be a possibility or do I have the same limitations at this point?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to process the zip file in chunks, instead of reading it all into memory.

One library that claims to do this is https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stream-zip